# Connect to Azure VM in Portal

Tags: azure, ssh, virtual-machine, connect

I have seen tutorials on how to connect to a Data Science VM (running Linux) in the web-portal. Just click connect, and it will download a desktop client. However, I get the following message:

*To connect to your Linux virtual machine using SSH, use the following command: ssh testuser@IP.Address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click Connect for a Windows VM, your browser will download an RDP file for you to use. To connect to a Linux VM, either

1. Install a desktop SSH client like [putty](http://www.putty.org/) and connect with your VM settings, or
2. Start the [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview) inside the Portal, then run the SSH command you received when you clicked Connect.

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize that difference between Windows and Linux. With a windows VM I am now able to connect to the desktop of that VM.

I manage to connect in the Azure Cloud Shell, but how do I actually get access to the desktop on the VM running Linux, as for Windows? For instance, I want to perform analyses with R. I guess that is not something you do from the Azure Cloud Shell.

Comment: The Linux VM runs X2Go for a graphical server. There are instructions on the [Ubuntu DSVM page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/dsvm-ubuntu-intro) for setting up your client and connecting. You should also think about whether you need to connect to a graphical desktop. Many commands are available through SSH, Jupyter notebooks are available through JupyterHub, and R is available vis RStudio Server.